# Unit tests for a project with multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

Let's say I have a project with 5 targets, all of them have its own module name. How can I use the same unit tests across modules?

To access internal stuff, I have to add @testable import ModuleName, but this ModuleName is different for every target.

I definitely don't want to do smth like this in every file:

```
#if Target1
@testable import Target1ModuleName
#elseif Target2
@testable import Target2ModuleName
#endif
```

Comment: I usually have a unit tests target for each module. This works pretty well.

Comment: I do have, but what about common tests for common functionality? You don't want to have five exact files for 5 targets.

Comment: Are all those different modules implementing the same functionality? Or are you trying to do some integation tests across modules? In case of integration tests regular imports should be enough, since you probably only want to test public interfaces. Internal stuff can be tested with @testable in the test target specific to a single module.

Comment: They have common business logic, but different UI. And I want to add tests for this common functionality.

Comment: Don't you have a separate target for the business logic? Normally this should be extracted into a framework to keep everything cleaner.

Comment: It's in the same project right now.

Comment: My recommendation is to do a "File - New Traget - Cocoa Touch Framework" and move everything there. But if you want to keep your project structure isn't importing a single target enough? Since the BL is common to all targets?

Comment: @marosoaie I need to think and check how this can be achieved. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you got any solutions to this problem?

Comment: I also want to find the way too. I'm in trouble.

Comment: @KiranJasvanee I ended up by adding usual files to the test target (Target Membership on the left in XCode)

Comment: @Oleshko okay. So we have created two same files for testing for different targets!

Comment: Try to define script that will add '@testable import *Target*' to all tests.

Comment: more details: https://oleb.net/blog/2017/03/keeping-xctest-in-sync/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you have some common functionality across your 5 targets that you want to unit test with a single test target. I will advise you to extract all your common functionality across targets into a single target and create a test target for this common target to test all common functionalities.